# Extra byte in C++ sizeof in class

Tags: c++, sizeof

Assuming the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

class FooBool
{ bool a; };

class FooUint16
{ uint16_t a; };

class FooBoth
{ bool a; uint16_t b;};

class FooThree
{ bool a; uint16_t b; uint16_t c; };

int main()
{
    // Expected 1; Result: 1
    { bool a;      std::cout << "bool:      " << sizeof(a) << std::endl; }
    // Expected 2; Result: 2
    { uint16_t a;  std::cout << "uint16_t:  " << sizeof(a) << std::endl; }
    // Expected 1; Result: 1
    { FooBool a;   std::cout << "FooBool:   " << sizeof(a) << std::endl; }
    // Expected 2; Result: 2
    { FooUint16 a; std::cout << "FooUint16: " << sizeof(a) << std::endl; }
    // Expected 3 (1 + 2); Result: 4
    { FooBoth a;   std::cout << "FooBoth:   " << sizeof(a) << std::endl; }
    // Expected 5 (1 + 2 + 2); Result: 6
    { FooThree a;  std::cout << "FooThree:  " << sizeof(a) << std::endl; }

    return 0;
}
```

Where does the extra byte for FooBoth and FooThree come from?

It's not using any virtual classes, is it? Is there an overhead per variable? If so, why is there only one in FooThree?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/struct/padding.html

Comment: You should read up on struct padding. Note that these results are not guaranteed by the standard; you may get different results with different compilers, different compilation flags, or using pragmas.

Comment: Ah, learned something new today. Thanks!